# OpenOPC timeout error

Tags: python

I am using python and OpenOPC to connect to a SCADA server.  My tags read OK
except after a random number of reads (anywhere between 30 and 50) I get
a timeout error.

```
File"test7.py", line 12 in <module>
value=opc.read(group='mygroup')
File "C:\OpenOPC\src\OpenOPC.py" line 619, in read
    return list(results)
File "C:\OpenOPC\src\OpenOPC.py" line 537, in iread
raise TimeoutError, 'Callback:Timeout waiting for data'
OpenOPC.TimeoutError:Callback: Timeout waiting for data
```

Is there anyone experienced with OpenOPC that might know how to resume
on the error, or ignore the error and continue.  I don't mind missing 
the odd value as long as the program does not crash.

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
import OpenOPC

opc = OpenOPC.client()
import datetime, threading, time
opc.connect('Citect.OPC.1')
tags = ['Loop_3_SP']
opc.read(tags, group='mygroup', update=1)
while True:
  value = opc.read(group='mygroup')
  print value
  time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just surround your code by a try catch block like this:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
import OpenOPC

opc = OpenOPC.client()
import datetime, threading, time
opc.connect('Citect.OPC.1')
tags = ['Loop_3_SP']
opc.read(tags, group='mygroup', update=1)
while True:
  try:
     value = opc.read(group='mygroup')
     print value
  except OpenOPC.TimeoutError:
     print "TimeoutError occured"

  time.sleep(10)
```

This should catch the Error and only print that it occured. If you don't want that anything happens in case of the TimeoutError, just user `pass` instead of the print statement.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This stops the routine from crashing, and allows it to continue.  I can now look to the underlying problem of the timeout.